# Is a FIN_WAIT2 state ever due to a close-connection initiator?

Tags: sockets, posix, tcp, netstat

I'm doing a bit of POSIX socket programming and am running into a problem. I've wrote an application that uses nonblocking sockets. Because I'm currently developing a client against a server that is in develop, bad application level messages occasionally get sent. When this happens, my only way to recover is to completely re-establish a connection to force the communication to a known state.

I reset the connection by issuing a POSIX "close()" on the non-blocking socket. I then request a new a socket and re-establish connection.

However, one thing I've discovered is that all of resets lead to a "FIN_WAIT2" on the old connections. When running a netstat command, there are a ton of FIN_WAIT2 that have no PIDs associated with them (I guess these are considered orphaned and could try a kernel connection timeout?).

Anyways, I'm curious why all of these old connections are stacking up in the netstat. I've done a bit of reading up on TCP states, and it seems that the FIN_WAIT2 I'm seeing is due to the server (i.e. not the closing initiator in my case) isn't responding with a message that it successfully closed. Why is this?

Is a FIN_WAIT2 typically associated with a bug in the non-close initiator side? Or is it possible that I'm doing something in my application that prevents the FIN message from being received? Does the fact I'm using non-blocking sockets have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, yes, you probably have a bug on the non-close-initiator side. It has nothing to do with non-blocking sockets though. Non-blocking sockets only affect interactions between your application and its own operating system.

It's important to understand that *both* sides must terminate a socket connection in order for the state to get properly cleaned up. It sounds like your server is not closing its end of the socket. One possible scenario:

- Server creates listening socket, binds it, etc.
- Server calls `accept`
- Client calls `connect` creating the connection (TCP state on both sides moves to `ESTABLISHED`
- `send` / `recv` / `send` / `recv` / etc (state still `ESTABLISHED`)
- Client calls `close`; client OS sends `FIN` packet to server (client OS moves socket state to `FIN_WAIT1`)
- Server OS sends `ACK` to acknowledge the client machine's `FIN` (server OS moves socket state to `CLOSE_WAIT`; client OS moves socket state to `FIN_WAIT2`)
- Server (program) never closes its socket, and hence server OS never sends `FIN`, so client OS will maintain the socket in `FIN_WAIT2` state. (Server socket state says in `CLOSE_WAIT`)

The client-side socket state could stay in `FIN_WAIT2` state for a long time, or even forever, depending on the OS implementation. Linux, for example, has a tunable variable `tcp_fin_timeout` that specifies how long an otherwise idle connection will remain in `FIN_WAIT2`; but the TCP standard does not specify a time-out for `FIN_WAIT2`. (Note that the client *program* is not aware of any of this. It has closed the socket, the socket file descriptor has been destroyed and the socket is no longer accessible to it; this is all handled by the operating system.)

If that is what happened, you could try restarting the server program (because when you terminate the server process, the server's operating system will automatically close all its open files, and that will cause `FIN`s to be sent on any still-open sockets). I think you will see that restarting the server causes all those client-side sockets to move into `TIME_WAIT` state, where they will stay for a short time before disappearing on their own. (There *is* a timeout mechanism specified for `TIME_WAIT`.)

See also the TCP State Diagram:

[image: TCP State Diagram]